# UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad without a done button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uikeyboard

How can we implement UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad so that it will have a 'done' button? By default it does not have one.

Comment: What do you mean by implementing keyboard, You want to hide keyboard or any thing elss.

Comment: No... Just that there will not be a done button in the keyboard

Comment: Dear number pad not having any Done button.so your question is not valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I am not wrong then You want to ask as to how to add a custom "Done" button to keyboard for UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad . In that case this might be helpful. Declare a UIButton *doneButton in.h and add the following code to .m file

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard {
    // create custom button
    if (doneButton == nil) {
        doneButton  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53)];
    }
    else {
        [doneButton setHidden:NO];
    }

    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard = nil;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}

- (void)doneButtonClicked:(id)Sender {
//Write your code whatever you want to do on done button tap
//Removing keyboard or something else
}
```

I am using the same in my application and the button's frame are thus adjusted, You can thus call [self addButtonToKeyboard ] whenever you need to show up the done button over the keyboard. UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad has no Done button otherwise.[image]

Comment: I have a problem with the line UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1]; i get emty array with no subviews

Comment: Where exactly do you get a blank array. In case of a keyboard being present on screen you will get atleast one item in array for sure i.e the keyboard.

Comment: I have added the call to this function once in keyboardwilllshow and keyboarddidshow but I still get empty array

Comment: try to make a call at some other point when You make your textfield or Textview as first responder.

Answer (score 2):

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];


//Call this method 

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {


   UIButton *doneButton  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53)];
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
        else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 issue resolved. Thanks a million.

I had a problem with displaying the Done button.

Replaced:

```
 if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
     [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
```

which did not display the done button in iOS 5...

With:

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
 } else {
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
 }
```

Worked a treat. You're a star. Thanks, Nicola ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If anybody had a problem that the DONE button keeps popping up when you try to load other types of keyboards in the same app, I know a lot of apps out there have this issue.
Anyway, here is how I solved this:
In your ViewController ( the same viewcontroller that you added DONE button ) add this code ( as is ) and it should solve your problems with DONE button keep reappearing.
Hope it helps to some folks.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

} else {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

}