# Switching UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad Default View

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I'm curious, is there a way of switching the UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad textfield keyboard layout to the PhonePad? By default you get the Name Pad, then when you click the numbers it switches to the Phone Pad, is there a way of defaulting this style of keyboard to the Phone Pad and be able to switch to the Name Pad?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: I need this same functionality too. I want to start on the number "side" of the NamePhonePad keyboard. Did you ever figure this out, or did you end up doing something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can keyboard of type UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad be made to start in phone mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489939/can-keyboard-of-type-uikeyboardtypenamephonepad-be-made-to-start-in-phone-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is working or not

Please try with **`UITextField appearance`**
put this sample code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

## Objective C

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];
```